# the callback passed to evhttp_request_new might get NULL

Tags: http, libevent

The following function is a callback passed to `evhttp_request_new()`.

My code sometime abort because of assert fail. 
  I am confusing that what may cause the pointer req to get NULL?

```
void http_request_done(struct evhttp_request *req, void *arg)
{
    assert(req); //assert fail here
}
```

Comment: Hi can you post your code.

Answer (score 0):

The callback passed to evhttp_request_new might get `NULL` if there was a timeout.